# Stripe Payment Link creates new customer

Tags: stripe-payments

We have to use payment links as were coming from a native desktop app  on MacOS and Windows, Stripe has no support here.

The native desktop apps do not have a web-view.

Using the following API with url params.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#url-parameters

```
const paymentLink = await stripe.paymentLinks.create({
    line_items: [
        {
            price: price.id,
            quantity: 3,
            //
        },
    ],
});
```

The url on the frontend opens as such (note to "client_reference_id")

```
final url = link + "?client_reference_id=$customerId&prefilled_email=${stripeCustomer!.email}";
```

The key url params are added.

The problem is, is that "client_reference_id" is ignored and a new customer is created on the Stripe dashboard, this is no good for making payments as we generate the payment for a specific account created on the database.

Any ideas what I could do here?

---

We tried checkout session but there is no way to open from a link. :-/

Comment: When you say your application lacks web access, does this mean it has no way to interact with either Stripe or a server you control?

The Payment Link documentation explains that the `client_reference_id` is a unique string for mapping the payment within your systems, it does not correlate to existing Stripe objects such as Customers. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#url-parameters

Checkout Sessions sound like they'd be a better fit, but if your application can't interact with servers then leveraging them may not be possible.

Comment: It can interact with the internet and the server yes. But it cannot open a web-view hence the link. It seems like payment link is fairly useless then, not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Not sure how you get to it being useless in this case, it's just not a fit for your use-case right? What you need to do is likely use Checkout instead directly. You make a request to your server where you create a Session with the right customer id (stored in your database). PaymentLinks are more for the ability to share a URL with many customers to pay for the same thing.

Comment: @koopajah unforteuntely check sessions don't have a web/tab acceptor or link generator for native desktop apps.

Comment: @OliverDixon I don't know what you call a "web/tab acceptor" but a Checkout Session has a `url` property that is the URL to redirect the customer to. It's no different from a PaymentLink that has a URL that you can hit that then creates a Checkout Session for you

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to this question. So the generic payment link does not work with a customer id, however you can create a session and attach a customer id to it. The session object will return with a url.

Example:

```
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [{ price: price_id, quantity: 1 }],
        mode: 'subscription',
        success_url: 'https://app.seedscout.com',
        cancel_url: 'https://app.seedscout.com',
        customer: cus_id,
    });
```

You can find more information in their documentation here.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create

Answer (score 2):

Important to note: Stripe has requirements for the format of `customer_reference_id:`

> `client_reference_id` can be composed of alphanumeric characters,
> dashes, or underscores, and be any value up to 200 characters. Invalid
> values are silently dropped and your payment page will continue to
> work as expected.

I was tearing my hair out trying to work out why `client_reference_id` wasn't being passed, and it looks like this was the issue – I was separating two values with a period.